# how to print huge reports in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, report

I have a web app that prints reports, most are just one page, or two, so I just create a component that shows the data and print it.

But I have this one report that can have thousands of lines, with a custom format, Flash will slow down with this.

Is it posible to print it without showing the actual data on screen? or is there a component to print reports with custom format?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess i'll answer my own question saying that the best way to create reports is generating a pdf file on server.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my print preview example that you can print as many pages as you need. check it out http://blog.kreatx.com/2011/11/11/flex-printing-print-preview-pdf-generation/